# Inserting to cassandra table with a composite primary key from hadoop reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, composite-key

I'm using Apache Hadoop, MapReduce and Cassandra to run a MapReduce job that reads in from a Cassandra table, and outputs to another Cassandra table.

I have a few jobs that output to a table with a single primary key. For example, this table for counting the number of each type of word has a single key.

```
    CREATE TABLE word_count(
        word text,
        count int,
        PRIMARY KEY(text)
    ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
```

The associated reduce class looks a bit like this:

```
public static class ReducerToCassandra 
    extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, ByteBuffer, List<Mutation>>
{
    public void reduce(Text word, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values){
            sum += val.get();
        }

        org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column c 
                = new org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column();
        c.setName(ByteBufferUtil.bytes("count");
        c.setValue(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(sum));
        c.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Mutation mutation = new Mutation();
        mutation.setColumn_or_supercolumn(new ColumnOrSuperColumn());
        mutation.column_or_supercolumn.setColumn(c);

        ByteBuffer keyByteBuffer = ByteBufferUtil.bytes(word.toString());
        context.write(keyByteBuffer, Collections.singletonList(mutation));
    }
}
```

If I want to add an extra column, then I just need to add another mutation to the `List<Mutation>` already being output by `reduce` but I can't work out how to output to a table that has the new column in a composite primary key. For example, this table does the same as the one above, but also indexes words along with the hour of their publication.

```
    CREATE TABLE word_count(
        word text,
        publication_hour bigint,
        count int,
        PRIMARY KEY(word, publication_hour)
    ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
```

I've tried a few different approaches, like trying to output a custom `WritableComparable` (that holds both a word and a hour) and updating the `class` and `method` signatures and `job` configuration accordingly, but that makes `reduce` throw a `ClassCastException` when it tries to cast the custom `WritableComparable` to `ByteBuffer`.

I've tried building the appropriate column name with the `Builder`.

```
public static class ReducerToCassandra 
    //              MappedKey     MappedValue  ReducedKey  ReducedValues
    extends Reducer<WordHourPair, IntWritable, ByteBuffer, List<Mutation>>
{
    //                 MappedKey                  Values with the key wordHourPair
    public void reduce(WordHourPair wordHourPair, Iterable<IntWritable> values, 
    Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values){
        sum += val.get();
        }
        long hour = wordHourPair.getHourLong();

        org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column c 
            = new org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column();
        c.setName(ByteBufferUtil.bytes("count");
        c.setValue(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(sum));
        c.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Mutation mutation = new Mutation();
        mutation.setColumn_or_supercolumn(new ColumnOrSuperColumn());
        mutation.column_or_supercolumn.setColumn(c);

        //New Code
        List<AbstractType<?>> keyTypes = new ArrayList<AbstractType<?>>(); 
        keyTypes.add(UTF8Type.instance);
        keyTypes.add(LongType.instance);
        CompositeType compositeKey = CompositeType.getInstance(keyTypes);

        Builder builder = new Builder(compositeKey);
        builder.add(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(word.toString());
        builder.add(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(hour));

        ByteBuffer keyByteBuffer = builder.build();
        context.write(keyByteBuffer, Collections.singletonList(mutation));
    }
}
```

But that throws an `IOException`

```
java.io.IOException: InvalidRequestException(why:String didn't validate.)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.java:204)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:String didn't validate.)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result$batch_mutate_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:28232)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result$batch_mutate_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:28218)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:28152)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1069)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1055)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.java:196)
```

This question: [Cassandra CQL3 composite key not written by Hadoop reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566882/cassandra-cql3-composite-key-not-written-by-hadoop-reducer) seems to exhibit the kind of code I'm looking for, but it calls `context.write` with parameters of type `HashMap, ByteBuffer` and I'm not sure how I'd make `context.write` accept those params.

How can I get the data I want (word-hour keys, int values) into my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was to use Cassandra's CQL interface, rather than the Thrift API.

Now I can write to a table with a composite key by declaring the output key/value classes of my reduce class as "Map, List", then create a Map for the composite key, where the Key (of type string) is a column name, and the Value (of type ByteBuffer) is the columns value converted to a ByteBuffer with ByteBufferUtil.

For example, to write to a table defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    customer_id uuid,
    time timestamp,
    my_value int,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, time)
)
```

I can write:

```
String customerID = "the customer's id";
long time = DateTime.now().getMillis();
int myValue = 1;

Map<String, ByteBuffer> key = new Map<String, ByteBuffer>();
key.put("customer_id",ByteBufferUtil.bytes(customerID));
key.put("time",ByteBufferUtil.bytes(time));

List<ByteBuffer> values = Collections.singletonList(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(myValue));

context.write(key, values);
```